# Expectation of bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Could someone let me know if this looks correct?

Let $X$ denote the number of successes in n bernoulli trials and let $Y$ denote the corresponding number of failures. Find an expression for $E[X-Y]^2$.

Let, $Y=N-X$

So we have, $E[2X-N]^2$

Giving, $E[4X^2 -4XN + N^2]$

$4np((1-p)-np-n) + n^2$

Answer (score 2):

Since $E[X^2]=Var(X)+E[X]^2$, then

$$E[4X^2] = 4E[X^2] = 4(np(1-p)+(np)^2)$$

for a binomial random variable $X$ with parameters $n$ and $p$. So one of your signs is wrong.

Also, I'm pretty sure $E[X-Y]^2$ means $(E[X-Y])^2$ and not $E[(X-Y)^2]$. This seems to be the notation in a book like "A First Course in Probability" by Sheldon Ross.

Comment: Ok thanks, my technique was right so bar the possibility of a false interpretation of the premises. That would be the same notation I would use but that seemed too easy and I had seen it written the other way before.